# retrieve data from firerbase to infowindow

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, infowindow

In my app I'm trying to retrieve some data from Firebase to show them into two texviews of a custom infowindow. After put every marker on the map, on the onDataChange method I can get correctly all the names inside the logcat, but I can't set them in the textviews nameInfo and cityInfo.
Any ideas? Where's my error? Thanks in advance.

This is a screenshot of my database:[firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6rRt.png)

And this is my MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

DatabaseReference ref1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    //add markers method
    ref1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String latitude = childSnap.child("coords").child("latitude").getValue().toString();
                String longitude = childSnap.child("coords").child("longitude").getValue().toString();

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                double lon = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                LatLng cod = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });


    //add infowindows method
    if (mMap != null) {

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_infowindow, null);

                final TextView nameInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameinfowindow);
                final TextView cityInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityinfowindow);

                ref1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
                        Log.i("Count ", "" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());

                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String nome = postSnapshot.child("nome").getValue().toString();

                            nameInfo.setText(nome);

                            Log.i("nomi", nome);

                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }


                });

                return view;
            }


        });


    }

}
```

}

And this is my infowindow layout: user_infowindow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameinfowindow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="nome.."
        android:layout_gravity="top|start" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityinfowindow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="city.."
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your code look good. Do you have an error? What's happening?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't know..the logcat shows correct data and also getChildrenCount returns correct count, but nothing is shown inside nameInfo..I edited my question with the infowindow layout

Comment: Try to move the declaration of those TextView inside `onDataChange()` and inside the `for loop`. Does it work?

Comment: I've tried to move declarations inside method and for loop but nothing change :(

Comment: can you show your firebase strcture ?